# clarification for using TensorFlow tf. placeholder

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to the TensorFlow. Can anyone explain what does the shape represents in following `tf.placeholder`?

`tf.placeholder(tf.float,shape=[None, 128, 128, 3])`

`tf.placeholder(tf.float,shape=[None,3])`
It means we are setting 2*3 matrix

`tf.placeholder(tf.float,shape=[None,None,3])`
It means we have 3 dimensions like an image with RGB

Please correct me if I am wrong for the above two cases

Answer (score 1):

```
tf.placeholder(tf.float,shape=[None, 128, 128, 3])
```

It is a 4D shape where first dimension is undefined i.e. can be any integer number.

You would commonly see those in NeuralNetwork training, where this shape would represent, I would expect, a batch of images. In would be a list of, at least in definition, non defined length with RGB (3 channels) images of size 128x128.

If the size of images was non-constant you would see a shape `[None, None, None, 3]`.